# Mixed horizontal an vertical css with <menu><li>

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

I'm trying to creat a menu with mixed vertical an horizontal items. That's how the menu should look like:

> item 1     item 3     item 5     item 7
>   item 2     item 4     item 6     item 8

What i tried ist the following HTML:

```
<menu>  
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
</menu>
```

And CSS:

```
.navigation menu {
    float: right;
    margin-top:103px;
    width:683px;    
}
.navigation menu li {
    display:block;
    width: 115px;
    float: none;
    background-image:none;
    text-align:right;
}
.navigation menu li:nth-child(3) {
    float: left;
}
.navigation menu li:nth-child(4) {
    float: none;
}
.navigation menu li:nth-child(5) {
    float: left;
}
.navigation menu li:nth-child(6) {
    float: none;
}
```

But it doesn't work, i think, it's too much for CSS :)

Anybody got an idea? Thanks in advance for any help!

Greetings Est Ro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the odd elements floating left.

Make the even elements have no width (margin-right: -115px) and position them 155 px to the left and the apropiate distance to the bottom:

CSS

```
.menu {
    float: left;
    margin-top:13px;
    width:683px;    
}
.menu li {
    display:block;
    width: 115px;
    float: left;
    background-image:none;
    text-align:right;
}

.menu li:nth-child(even) {
    position: relative;
    top: 1.2em;
    left: -115px;
    margin-right: -115px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eERR7/1/)

Comment: It works great! Many Thanks! I just added display:block; to .menu an changed float: left; to float:right; an its aligned on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is set the menu items to

```
width:25%;
```

on each of your menu items and then just float them left. You can get rid of everything else. Also as a side do not use the menu tag is it deprecated. :)

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/eERR7/

**UPDATED FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/eERR7/2/

Comment: Hi, many thanks! I already tried this, but the problem is, that the output is in wrong order (see menu example in my first post). Thanks for the hint with the deprecated menu tag! I will change this asap :)

Comment: Hey there, so what you can do instead is place each of the two elements in your group in each of the li and mark those and block level. fiddle has been udpdated  :) Enjoy!

Comment: It works! Wow, thanks so much! 45 min. on Stackoverflow an I have 2 perfect solutions, thanks so much to everybody workin itg out!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? It's a little bit rusty but it my fit what you want.

I added some of the and changed a bit

```
.navigation menu li:nth-child(6) {
    float: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JXxU8/2/